# Angular interceptor - rxjs/map response field

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-http-interceptors

Responses do not return when following interceptor is applied

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      map(response => {
        if (response instanceof HttpResponse) {
          return response.body.data;
        }
        return response;
      })
    );
  }
```

I would like the 'data' field of each response to be the only one present in the original caller component

Why does it happen and how can I implement this better?

I otherwise have to explicitly add `pipe -> pluck('data')` for each request in my project

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        return next.handle(req).pipe(map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
            if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                event = event.clone({body: event.body.data});
            }
            return event;
        }));

    }
```

in that function subscribe you will get response.body as data